# How to run code on currently selected range of cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I have 12 columns of data. I am trying to transpose it into 12 columns of data, while keeping the absolute cell references in the formula.

[image: Image describing what I am talking about]

I am trying to make a macro that will allow me to select the range I need to execute this action on, and then copy each of the absolute formulas and paste them as is into the first column. How do I make the code start with my selection and not an absolute cell.

[image: This is what I have already]

I need to do it for all of my sheet, which requires running this action around 100 times.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. Instead, post the code itself (edit your question) so people can copy/paste it if they want to.

Comment: 0) post actual code, not image as previously mentioned. 1) get rid of .select like this: `Range("E4").FormulaR1C1 = "yourformula"` . this will speed up your code. 2) Some options you can research for macro: `Range("A1").Offset(#,#)`, `Selection.formula = ...`, `Dim RG as range, Set RG = Selection...` If you're trying to run the same thing on multiple sheets, you can use `Dim SH as worksheets, for each SH in thisworkbook.worksheets...`

Answer (score 1):

This can be an example and should help get you where you need to be.

---

First, you'll want to [avoid `Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba#:%7E:text=Probably%20the%20biggest%20thing%20you,however%2C%20it%20deserves%20special%20attention.), first and foremost.

Second, you'll want some dimensioned ranges, and you can use `application.transpose()` to move the items:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    With Sheets(1)
        Dim sourceRange As Range
        Set sourceRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(2, 2))
        Dim destinationRange As Range
        Set destinationRange = .Cells(5, 1)
        destinationRange.Resize(sourceRange.Rows.Count, sourceRange.Columns.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(sourceRange)
    End With
End Sub
```

Note the use of Dot notation is followed through the entire `range()`.

[image]